# python3のprint関数とwriteメソッドの違い

Tags: python, python3

以下のコードに何か違いはありますか？

```
file = open("sample.txt", "w", encoding="utf-8")
print("hello", file=file)
file.write("hello")
file.close()
```

python3ではprint文でファイル書き込みができますが、使い分ける状況などはありますか？

Comment: `print("hello", file=file)` と `file.write("hello")` に違いは有るか？　という意味でしょうか？

Answer (score 5):

"ファイルへの出力(書き込み)"という意味では一見同じですが、細かく見ると以下のような違いがあるようです。

> print : デフォルトでは出力の末尾に改行を追加する(変更は可能)。
> write : 渡された文字列をそのまま出力。文字列以外は受け取れない。

writeの場合は繰り返し実行した時、以下の通り文字列が繋がって出力されます。

```
write("Hello")
write("Hello")
write("Hello")
# => HelloHelloHello
```

参考:
[Python Tips：改行なしで文字列を出力したい](http://www.lifewithpython.com/2013/12/python-print-without-.html)

Answer (score 4):

> 使い分ける状況などはありますか？

`print` より `write` の方が速いです。
質問のような単純なケースで 1.5 〜 3 倍程度速いと思います。
また、`print` はバイナリモードで開いたファイルオブジェクトには使用できません（引数が bytes であっても、テキスト表現の文字列に変換して書き込み、失敗します）。

---

Python3 の `print` は文ではなく、[関数になっています](https://docs.python.jp/3/whatsnew/2.6.html#pep-3105-print-as-a-function)。